# Do Monsanto GM foods cause gluten-related illnesses?

Tags: nutrition, gmo

In a newly released video by RT they claim that "Future Epidemic? Monsanto GM foods cause gluten-related illnesses"
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyV001qX2i4

> 18 million of Americans suffer from gluten-related illnessess - **that's thanks to the genetically modified soya and corn they eat**, a survey reveals. Medical experts say it may become an epidemic for the next generation, prompting more and more Americans to choose a gluten free diet. RT's Marina Portnaya investigates the seeds of GMO-phobia.

Clearly stating that it is attributed by consumption of GMO food.

Digging further and finding the article on their site, reveals a different story: "GMOs linked to gluten disorders plaguing 18 million Americans - report"

http://rt.com/usa/gmo-gluten-sensitivity-trigger-343/

> **Genetically modified foods such as soy and corn may be responsible for a number of gluten-related maladies** including intestinal disorders now plaguing 18 million Americans, according to a new report released on Tuesday.

So here are the claims to verify:

1. Do Monsanto GM foods cause gluten-related illnesses
2. Can Genetically modified foods such as soy and corn be responsible for a number of gluten-related maladies (and how likely?)

P.S. I know similar topic has been discussed multiple times, but this is **specific to Gluten related illnesses** and in the light of recently released report.

[Is GM corn toxic?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8263/is-gm-corn-toxic)
[Is Genetically Modified food safe to consume?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/is-genetically-modified-food-safe-to-consume)

Comment: [This is the report in question as far as I can tell](http://responsibletechnology.org/media/images/content/Exploding-Gluten-Sensitivity_.pdf?key=32174740). It does not contain any actual study itself as far as I can tell, but there are a lot of individual claims in there.

Comment: Since gluten sensitivity has existed for a long time (the name *coeliac disease* is derived from a greek description of the disease about 2,000 years old) it seems a stretch to assume genetic modification causes it. The least evidence that would bee needed would be proof that related proteins are modified in GM foods and that the disease is more common among those who eat GM. Such evidence is missing.

Comment: RT is like Natural News or Realfarmancy, for every kernel of truth is a whole field of information they make up. When you search for more information, the first sites that come up are Mercola, NN, InfoWars and RT. That says it all really. Apparently this gluten claim was made up be anti-GM campaigner Jeffrey Smith: http://gmopundit.blogspot.com.au/2013/12/celiac-disease-foundation-plant.html

Comment: As a rule of thumb, almost any gluten-related news advocating a gluten free diet for everyone can be safely dumped on the trash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The report this is based on is ["Can Genetically Engineered Foods Trigger Gluten Sensitivity?"](http://responsibletechnology.org/media/images/content/Exploding-Gluten-Sensitivity_.pdf?key=32174740) published by the [Institute for responsible technology](http://responsibletechnology.org/). As far as I can tell this is not a peer-reviewed scientific paper.

On reading through it, the report makes a lot of small individual claims about the effect of GMOs, or the specific proteins inserted into GMOs like bt-toxin. Each of those claims would deserve a full post here, I'm not going to dissect all of them in this post.

But that is also not necessary, as the report does not actually show any causal link between GMOs and gluten sensitivity. It creates a narrative that implies this link, but in the end it even states that there is no sufficient evidence:

> While there is insufficient research to prove that GMO consumption 
>   causes gluten sensitivity, the evidence does show how it might, at
>   least,  exacerbate the symptoms, or contribute to the conditions that
>   might  lead to the development of sensitivity to gluten

This report was also criticized heavily by the [Celiac Disease Foundation](http://celiac.org/) in [this article](http://celiac.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/2013-12-04.pdf):

> The report, published last week by the Institute for Responsible
>   Technology (IRT), was "speculative," Celiac Disease Foundation CEO
>   Marilyn Geller told FoodNavigator-USA.
>
> "There has been no scientific
>   evidence put forward for a GMO/celiac disease link that is supported
>   by the CDF Medical Advisory Board."
>
> Meanwhile, plant geneticist Dr.
>   Wayne Parrott - professor of crop science at the University of Georgia
>   - claimed the report relied on "a handful of deeply flawed" studies and did not reference the "more than 1,000 studies that have been
>   published in refereed journals and which show that GM crops are as
>   safe as their counterparts."

Comment: thanks, great finds. I checked the original article and it does look as a collection of unrelated things, trying to prove some another point.