# Genetically modified crops

Tags: nutrition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What risks exist with GMO, but not with selective breeding?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/68/what-risks-exist-with-gmo-but-not-with-selective-breeding)

I heard that one of the reasons that people oppose GM food is because GM crops when digested create a protein that humans may not be able to process. Is there any truth to that claim?

Comment: can you source that claim?

Comment: You need to provide a source for the claim. Otherwise, one could simply make up any number of random claims, posting them. And once something appears online, then it is copied forever. This claim for example, is a VERY broad one, that seems to claim that all GM crops have something in them that is indigestible. What it is, you don't say. But many plants produce something that your digestive system won't process anyway. So you need to provide a specific claim, and it must be a claim from someplace that you can cite.

Comment: Not an exact 1:1 match, however the linked question more than covers this one.